# Generating Shared Access Signature URI from console application for Azure Storage Account Access > how to output results to file?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, console, azure-storage

## PROBLEM

I am using the code below to generate a SAS URI for a Azure Storage Account which works a treat.

However when executing the code the resulting console application window displays the relevant URI string but I am unable to copy the value.

## QUESTION

Easy question hopefully , what has to be added to the code below to output the URI to a text file ?

> {
>
> using System.IO;
>
> using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
>
> using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
>
> using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
>
> using System;
>
> using System.Collections.Generic;
>
> using System.Linq;
>
> using System.Text;
>   using System.Threading.Tasks;
>
> namespace SAS
>
> {
>       class Program
>       {
>           static void Main(string[] args)
>           {
>
> ```
> //Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
> CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
>
> //Create the blob client object.
> CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
>
> //Get a reference to a container to use for the sample code, and create it if it does > not exist.
> CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("sascontainer");
> container.CreateIfNotExists();
>
> //Insert calls to the methods created below here...
>
>
> //Generate a SAS URI for the container, without a stored access policy.
> Console.WriteLine("Container SAS URI: " + GetContainerSasUri(container));
> Console.WriteLine();
>
> //Require user input before closing the console window.
> Console.ReadLine();
>     }
>
>
>
>     static string GetContainerSasUri(CloudBlobContainer container)
>     {
>         //Set the expiry time and permissions for the container.
>         //In this case no start time is specified, so the shared access signature > becomes valid immediately.
>         SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
>         sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(4);
>         sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | > SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List;
>
>         //Generate the shared access signature on the container, setting the > constraints directly on the signature.
>         string sasContainerToken = > container.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);
>
>         //Return the URI string for the container, including the SAS token.
>         return container.Uri + sasContainerToken;
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> }
>   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the answer is rather simple. To save the output to a file, can't you just do:

```
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\output.txt", "Container SAS URI: " + GetContainerSasUri(container))
```

If you want to copy the contents from command prompt, here's what you would need to do:

1. Right click on the command prompt.
2. Click **`Mark`**.
3. Drag the cursor to select the text.
4. Hit **`Enter`** key to copy the selected text to clipboard.

Or ... am I completely misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Console.exe right click functions are disabled for some reason hence the post. Thank you for the File.Write line , this was what I needed. Powershell script is a useful solution and probably should have been my initial approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the SAS string from console, Powershell will be a quicker approach.

Firstly ensure you installed Azure PowerShell, and authenticate your Azure PowerShell session by either Add-AzureAccount or Import-AzurePublicSettingsFile

Then, you have created your storage account with **account_name**, and a container with **container_name**:

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName account_name -StorageAccountKey (Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName account_name).Primary
$container = (Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name container_name -Context $context).CloudBlobContainer
$sp = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPolicy
$sp.SharedAccessExpiryTime = [System.DateTime]::Now.AddHours(4)
$sp.Permissions = ([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPermissions]::Write -bor [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPermissions]::List)
$uriwithsas = $container.Uri.AbsoluteUri + $container.GetSharedAccessSignature($sp)
echo $uriwithsas
```

Comment: Peferct thank you. Should have been my original approach , console code snippets were first thing i found to help generate SAS uri for third party.

Comment: Getting an error during execution. If possible can you please elaborate on this PS script to include everything required to generate a signature (include subscriptionID , storage account , container name examples). Thank you for any help.

Comment: update the script a little about generating the context